# ERROR Basic Authentication failure: tenant domain mismatch for user :user@domain.com in WSO2 API Manager 4.1.0

Tags: wso2, basic-authentication, wso2-api-manager, wso2-enterprise-integrator

I am trying [Secure API by BasicAuth](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/4.1.0/design/api-security/api-authentication/secure-apis-using-basic-authentication/) in `WSO2 API Manager 4.1.0` GA Release.

- There is Backend Service which was protected by Basic Auth Mechanism(Username: `user1@testdomain.com`, Password: `apimtestpwd`), Hosted this backend in WSO2 APIM by follows below mentioned steps.
- BasicAuth enabled Under `API Configurations section` --> `Runtime` in Publisher
  [image: Publisher]
- BasicAuth Credentials are provided Under `API Configurations section` --> `Endpoints`

[image: basicauth]

- Published the same and now It's visible in `Devportal`. There is no subscription added as this was protected with Basic Authentication

[image: devportal]

- When I tested via `Try Out` or `postman` getting `403 Forbidden` ERROR as response

`{ "code": "900908", "message": "Resource forbidden ", "description": "Resource forbidden " }`

Noticed below ERROR Log in `wso2carbon.log`

```
[2023-03-30 20:01:49,291] ERROR - BasicAuthAuthenticator Basic Authentication failure: tenant domain mismatch for user :user1@testdomain.com
[2023-03-30 20:01:49,291]  WARN - APIAuthenticationHandler API authentication failure due to Resource forbidden
```

PS: User added in wso2 carbon portal under `Users and Roles` Section.

@Lakshitha suggested added below lines in `deployment.toml` file

```
[super_admin]
username = "admin"
password = "admin"
create_admin_account = true
[tenant_mgt]
enable_email_domain= true

[apim.throttling]
#username = "$ref{super_admin.username}@carbon.super"
username = "admin@wso2.com@testdomain.com@carbon.super"

[apim.throttling.policy_deploy]
username = "$ref{super_admin.username}@carbon.super"

[apim.throttling.jms]
#username="admin!wso2.com!carbon.super"
username="admin!wso2.com!testdomain.com!carbon.super"
password = "$ref{super_admin.password}"
```

API Request is not reached to backend URL server. How to resolve this issue?

Comment: This error happens when the publisher's tenant domain is different from user's tenant domain. Could you check that?

Comment: Hi @sanoJ There is no tenant creation . so I believe this is deployed under carbon.super which is default one. Do i need to create new tenant called "testdomain" in carbon portal under Configure --> Add new tenant option?

Comment: What are the credentials that you have used to invoke this API? (Not the backend) user1@testdomain.com or admin credentials?

Comment: Hi @Lakshitha I have invoked WSO2 APIM api using the credentials which is used for backend(ie user1@testdomain.com )

Comment: @Justin after setting enable_email_domain= true, this should work. Can you share the request you used to invoke the API?

Comment: Hi @sanoJ Do i need to enable only enable_email_domain=true or other configurations such as  apim.throttling, apim.throttling.policy_deploy, apim.throttling.jms which i updated in question. please clarify on the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is with the user that you are invoking the API. If you are using email address as username (eg: user1@testdomain.com), you have to explicitly enable this (Check this [doc](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/install-and-setup/setup/security/logins-and-passwords/maintaining-logins-and-passwords/#setup-an-e-mail-login)). If not, server belives the part after `@` as a tenant domain and see for an associated tenant domain.

I think that should be the reason for having this error in the backend.

In your scenario you have basic auth in two layers,

1. Backend endpoint security
2. API security

You need to have correct username password credentials for the 2.API security part. These username, password pair has to be included in the wso2 userstore and that's how APIM validates the request.

The credentials for 1. Backend security does not have this requirement as the validation is done from the backend. Not from the APIM server.

Edit:
You can't use user1@testdomain.com to invoke the API exposed via the API Manager. This user is associated with the backend and for Basic auth at the APIM layer, you need to invoke with a user that is already included in the WSO2 userstore.

Once the server validate the authenticity of the user, it pass the request to backend and for this call, server generates a new basic auth header using the configurations that you have set in the endpoint security section (user1@testdomain.com and password). In this backend call, API Manager acts as the client and send the request to the backend server using the basic auth credentials.

Comment: Hi @Lakshitha,

I have already added user "user1@testdomain.com" in WSO2 Carbon console which will be added in WSO2 userstore. right? As per your suggestion, deployment.toml configuration updated . please check that and let me know if any change required there or not.

Comment: Have you followed the configurations and different steps mentioned in https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/install-and-setup/setup/security/logins-and-passwords/maintaining-logins-and-passwords/#setup-an-e-mail-login?

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @Lakshitha and @sanoJ , I have added below mentioned line in `<API-M_HOME>/repository/conf/deployment.toml`

```
[tenant_mgt]
enable_email_domain= true
```

and also specific user is onboarded in WSO2 APIM Carbon portal by navigating to `Main --> Users and Roles --> Add`

In my case, username as `user1@testdomain.com` and password as `apimtestpwd`

Post that API hits are happening and i could get backend response as well.

Many Thanks to @Lakshitha and @sanoJ for helping to resolve my issue.